# Dropdown picker in sectionList react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-sectionlist

I try to render a dropdown-picker (react-native-dropdownpicker) in a sectionlist but it's impossable to scroll the content of the dropdown. It only shows the first results.

I tried many things with zIndex, view with flex: 1 as parent but im unable to find the solution.

Is it possible to render in a sectionlist or should i be looking for another solution?

[sectionlist with dropdown-picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0wJl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

**List Modes**

You have 3 options when choosing the list mode.

- `DEFAULT`
- `FLATLIST`
- `SCROLLVIEW`
- `MODAL`

  listMode="`FLATLIST`"

**Notes**

The `FlatList` component shouldn't be nested inside `ScrollView` or you'll come across the `VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews` warning.
If this happens to you and you only have a few items, consider using the `SCROLLVIEW` mode. Otherwise, you have to use the `MODAL` mode.

Take a look at this snack:

https://snack.expo.dev/@devsaeedhabibi/dropdown-picker